# I got "PLS-00103 : Encountered the symbol "CREATE" ..." when I try to declare a directory inside a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, text, plsql

I am trying to create a txt file using "PL/SQL" with "utl_file" but I got some problems. Here is my code

```
procedure testFile Is
  out_File Utl_File.File_Type;
  CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY tmp AS 'C:\Users\jsnow\Documents';

  GRANT read, write ON DIRECTORY tmp TO jack;
Begin
  out_file:=utl_file.fopen(tmp,'test.txt','W');
  utl_file.put_line(out_file,'Test!');
  utl_file.fclose(out_file);
  Exception when others then
    Dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm ||'-------'||Sqlcode);
end testfile;
```

When I try to compile this script I get this error :

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:

          begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
          <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
          exists prior
```

Do you know how can I create a text file in a stored procedure?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would just like to reiterate Littlefoot's comment of "don't do that".  Trying to create objects and grant privileges within a procedure is evidence of very, very poor design.  There is no good reason that these actions cannnot/should not be done with simple SQL during application build.  That goes for all DDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be doing it in a procedure. Create directory (and grant privileges) out of it, at SQL level (not PL/SQL).

If you insist, then you'll have to use dynamic SQL, i.e. `execute immediate`:

```
procedure testFile Is
  out_File Utl_File.File_Type;
Begin
  execute immediate q'[CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY tmp AS 'C:\Users\jsnow\Documents']';
  execute immediate 'GRANT read, write ON DIRECTORY tmp TO jack';

  -- the rest of your code
end;
```

Comment: The problem is that I got "PLS00201 : identifier "TMP" must be declared" after compiling my code.

Comment: Yes, because you use a variable you never declared previously. It represents directory name, so - try with `out_file:=utl_file.fopen('TMP', 'test.txt', 'W');` i.e. provide directory **name** (you created with `create directory`).

Comment: I got "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges" after executing the "CREATE OR REPLACE" command. I think that I am not allowed to create a directory. Thank you for yout reply.

Comment: That's also possible. Directories are created by a privileged user (normally, it is SYS). Other users are allowed to *use* them, and that's done by SYS granting privileges to it. As I said in the first sentence: you shouldn't be doing it this way. Connect as SYS (or any other privileged user you have; if none, contact your DBA), create directory, grant privileges, and then just **use it** in your PL/SQL procedure.

Comment: One more thing: if you thought of switching everything to SYS and create procedures in its schema, then **DO NOT DO THAT**. SYS is special, it owns the database. If you screw something there, you'll probably destroy the database.